# Webscraping Data from Interactive Maps

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, maps

I was wondering if it is possible to scrape data from the following interactive map:

https://map.910ths.sa/

I tried to scrape it following the instructions [here](https://onlinejournalismblog.com/2017/05/10/how-to-find-data-behind-chart-map-using-inspector/)

However, after clicking on Network, then XHR, I get the following error:

> ```
> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}
> ```

I understand that some interactive maps such as ones designed with Microsoft Power BI are impossible/difficult to scrape, but I was wondering if we can find the data underlying the interactive map above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example interactive map uses an API for its data, located at https://api.map.910ths.sa/api/graphql/ . It takes POST requests. The output data is something like this:

```
{"data":{"businesses":{"aggregationByArea":{"areaBuckets":[{"area":{"id":"city-3","location":{"latitude":24.699999961,"longitude":46.733330032}},"size":147136}]},"size":147136}}}
```

You can find the data reqeusts as graphql:

[image]

I suggest you read into scraping API's with python:

- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/web-scraping-with/9781491910283/ch04.html